# Remove a parent activity link in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-manifest, navigationbar

I just removed the parent activity setting in the Android Manifest of my app, but when I run the app on an android device, in the action bar is still shown the back simbol on the right (even if it doesn't work if I touch on it). How can I remove that?

Here is the manifest's section about that activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activities.AllSitesActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

and here the menu of that activity:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.alessandroc.mynews.Activities.AllSitesActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="103"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_new_folder"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:title="@string/action_new_folder"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_new"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_new"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

Comment: remove `actionbar.setHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` from code

Comment: Do you want actionbar in your screen or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting this in the onCreate() method of your activity :

> getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
//or ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar()
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); 
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
}
```